# in Flutter Provider How to check when data received in consumer is updated

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, google-maps-flutter

How can we check if data receiving in `consumer` via `provider` is updated or changed, I want to add a buffer to check the `Lat Lang` value before passing to `google_maps_flutter`, I want to check the value 5 times before passing to the `google_maps_flutter` widget to update the location

```
Consumer<PuhserDataProvider>(builder: (context, data, child) {
          if (data.devicePusherData != null) {
            final lat = extractLat("${data.devicePusherData.gps}");
            final lang = extractLang("${data.devicePusherData.gps}");

            log.w(lat);
            log.w(lang);

            return GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(lat, lang),
                zoom: 16,
              ),
              markers: [
                Marker(
                    markerId: MarkerId('0'),
                    position: LatLng(lat, lang),
                    onTap: () =>
                        setState(() => selectedPoint = LatLng(lat, lang)))
              ].toSet(),
              onTap: (point) => setState(() => selectedPoint = null),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            );
          }
        }),
```

the provider used is a change notifier provider, Default constructer functions call the pusher to get values, the setter, and getter function to retrieve values.

```
    class PuhserDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Pusher pusher;
  Logger log = getLogger("PuhserDataProvider");
  DevicePusherData _devicePusherData;
  DevicePusherData get devicePusherData => _devicePusherData;

  OBDPuhserData _obdPusherData;
  OBDPuhserData get obdPusherData => _obdPusherData;

  PuhserDataProvider(String imei, String token, String pusherKey)
      : pusher = Pusher(
          pusherKey,
          PusherOptions(
              cluster: 'eu',
              authEndpoint: AUTH_URL,
              auth: PusherAuth(headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
              })),
        ) {
    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe('private-$imei-send');

    channel.bind('obd-event',
        (data) => _setOBDData(OBDPuhserData.fromJson(json.decode(data)[0])));

    channel.bind(
        'deviceevent',
        (data) =>
            _setDeviceData(DevicePusherData.fromJson(json.decode(data)[0])));
  }

  _setDeviceData(DevicePusherData devicePusherData) {
    this._devicePusherData = devicePusherData;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  _setOBDData(OBDPuhserData obdPusherData) {
    this._obdPusherData = obdPusherData;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check value 5 times inside your PusherDataProvider class. After checking 5 times and if update or changed occurs then you can call notifyListeners() method.

Comment: if you show the PusherDataProvider class, it helps to give better solution

Comment: thanks, @TDM for your Kind comment, I have added the code for PusherDataProvider class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this by 02 ways**

1. Using Selector() instead of Consumer().
2. Using PuhserDataProvider() class.

---

**1. Using Selector() instead of Consumer().**

> An equivalent to Consumer that can filter updates by selecting a limited amount of values and prevent rebuild if they don't change.

---

**2. Using PuhserDataProvider() class.**

> Check your logic before calling notifyListers()

Here

```
class PuhserDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Pusher pusher;
  Logger log = getLogger("PuhserDataProvider");


  //I changed _devicePusherData into _devicePusherDataGps
  //I dont know Data type of your .gps , so temperary i said it as Object , you need to change it
  Object _devicePusherDataGps;

  //I changed devicePusherData into devicePusherDataGps 
  //I dont know Data type of your .gps , so temperary i said it as Object , you need to change it
  Object get devicePusherDataGps => _devicePusherDataGps;

  //counter variable with default value 1 ,this will increment when each time value changed
  int counter = 1;

  PuhserDataProvider(String imei, String token, String pusherKey)
      : pusher = Pusher(
          pusherKey,
          PusherOptions(
              cluster: 'eu',
              authEndpoint: AUTH_URL,
              auth: PusherAuth(headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
              })),
        ) {
    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe('private-$imei-send');

    channel.bind(
        'deviceevent',
        (data) =>
            _setDeviceData(DevicePusherData.fromJson(json.decode(data)[0])));
  }

  _setDeviceData(DevicePusherData devicePusherData) {
    if (_devicePusherDataGps == null) {
      _devicePusherDataGps = devicePusherData.gps;
    }
    else{
      if (devicePusherData.gps != _devicePusherDataGps) {
      //This will check value changes for 5 times.
        if (counter == 5) {
          counter = 1;
          this._devicePusherDataGps = devicePusherData.gps;
          notifyListeners();
        } else {
          counter++;
        }
      }
    }
    
  }

}
```

In above class, setter function was changed only to set **gps** value. Because in your question you said that you want to check **Lat Lang value** individually, So I create seperate setter method for it.

---

And Now in Consumer widget you need to change `data.devicePusherData.gps` into `data.devicePusherDataGps`

```
final lat = extractLat("${data.devicePusherDataGps}");
final lang = extractLang("${data.devicePusherDataGps}");
```

Hope this will help you. If you have any question on above, please comment I will try to help. (Sometimes code just have syntax errors, because I didnt have your json model class to import)

Comment: thanks TDM for you kind perfect answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your class should be looks like:

```dart
PusherDataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final Object _value;

  set value(Object value) {
    if (value != _value) {
      _value = value;
      // Notify listeners only when data changed
      notifyListeners();
    }

    Object get value => _value;
  }
}
```

So now yor `Consumer`'s builder will be called when data is changed. Declare a counter variable which will be checked inside builder.

Comment: Thanks, @BambinoUA I am looking  into implementing code as per your instructions